how to integrate React Hook Form in existing email function
I have an email contact form, and now I want to implement validation with React Hook Form and Zod. This seems a lot thougher as I was hoping for.
This is my email send function that get's called when the contact form is submitted:
const handleSubmitForm = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget)
        const { fullName, senderEmail, phone, message } = Object.fromEntries(formData)

        const finalHtml = render(
            <ContactFormEmail message={message as string} senderEmail={senderEmail as string} />,
            {
                pretty: true
            }
        )

        const finalText = render(
            <ContactFormEmail message={message as string} senderEmail={senderEmail as string} />,
            {
                plainText: true
            }
        )

        try {
            const res = await fetch('/api/sendEmail.json', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    from: 'john@doe.com',
                    to: 'john@doe.com',
                    subject: 'new message from contact form',
                    reply_to: senderEmail,
                    html: finalHtml,
                    text: finalText
                })
            })
        } catch (error: any) {
            setError('root', {
                message: error.response.data.message
            })
        }
    }

I want to call this method when the form is submitted, and also invoke React Hook Form validation at the same time.
I tried to integrate React Hook Form by calling this function like this:
handleSubmit(handleSubmitForm)

I also tried to replace the parameter in the handleSubmitForm method like this:
const handleSubmitForm = async (data) => {
...
}

But that does not work and TypeScript is complaining:
"Argument of type '(e: React.FormEvent) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SubmitHandler'.
Types of parameters 'e' and 'data' are incompatible.
Type 'FormData' is missing the following properties from type 'FormEvent': nativeEvent, currentTarget, target, bubbles, and 11 more.ts(2345)"
Does someone know how I can call handleSubmitForm when submitting the the form and invoke React Hook Form at the same time?
Thanks a lot for your help,
Anthony
